# How to use different session id for same user across different django project with same database

Tags: django-users, django-middleware, django-sessions, session-management

I have 2 Django projects running on different domains. Both are using the same database and the same models. One project is in 2.7 and another project is in 3.7.

When user login into one domain, it logs out the user from other domain.

I have login in chrome using one domain. It works and 1 entries exists in django session. but when i login into chrome using another domain. Still 1 previous sessionid exists in django_sessions but when i refresh first domain page, it log me out from first domain and now django_sessions does not have previous first domain sessionid in db.

How can i restrict him to not logging the user out from one domain on login into another domain?

Comment: By default, sessions are stored in the database - that could be causing the conflict between the two apps. Try switching to a different sessions storage technique - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/.

Comment: Entries from django_session table are not deleting on login. Entries from django_session are deleting  after login on page refresh.